# When to use Ruby vs When to use PHP

Tags: php, ruby

I've been learning Ruby, just for fun so far (no current projects require Ruby). I like it fine, but I also like PHP. I know it's a pointless, and often-asked question to "compare Ruby to PHP." That's not what I'm asking. Rather, I'd be curious as to examples of when one language makes sense over the other. It's all about having the right tool for the right job, after all, and I'm trying to get a better sense of what the "right job" for Ruby is.

I'm not as interested in points such as the size of the community or ease of deployment - I imagine as Ruby grows in popularity this will be less of an issue vs PHP. Rather, in the world of getting things done online, what kinds of jobs does Ruby naturally work as a more appropriate solution than PHP? Also, just to be clear, assume PHP5 written in a object-oriented manner :-)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm really tempted to throw in a comment along the lines of "Use PHP when you are a (derogatory comment about PHP programmers). Use Ruby when you are a (derogatory comment about Ruby programmers). Really, the two languages target very similar spaces (you aren't, for instance, comparing Python and Assembler), and language wars help nobody.

Comment: This is the very definition of a subjective question. I, for instance, would say "Use Rails when you want to build a website. Use PHP when you want to atone via self-flagellation"

Comment: @meager: It may be a subjective question, but it's definitely not a definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this slide pretty interesting about Ruby and Ruby on Rails, I suggest you check it out

http://www.slideshare.net/dosire/when-to-use-ruby-on-rails-1308900

it even said Ruby is 2x slower than PHP

Honestly though, it is really good that you are liking both PHP and Ruby, Nice Assets to have.

Comment: Thanks! So from what I can gather, there's not really a definitive answer, but rather an intuitive "feel" that will develop with more use of a language - I suppose a bit analagous to when you choose to use if(condition { } vs if (condition): endif; style in PHP. A matter of circumstances and comfort/style, not readily generalizable.

Comment: I don't think the decision you came up with is entirely correct. Recently I came through a discussion in some group where they were saying PHP5 is faster than python, but File parsing in PHP is slower. So, they were suggesting to use Perl if you are developing a site that has heavy file parsing work. Therefore I think there is no such thing like "intuitive feel", it's engineering and everything must have a precised explanation. I am amazed seeing that no one know (or didn't share) the answer of this vital question!!!

Answer (score 2):

My view is to forget about classes of problems and use whatever language feels most natural for you. I've heard many people say that Ruby's syntax is annoying or that they just don't "get" the Ruby style.  I'd never try to convince these people that Ruby's the best candidate for their job, in the same way I'd never try to convince a French novelist to write in English or Chinese to gain a bigger audience.

One thing you get with Ruby is a general purpose language that can be applied outside web applications, but if that doesn't apply to you, follow your gut and pick the language that feels easiest.  That being said, do it *well*.  Dig into your language of choice, study other people's code, and become proficient. Maybe revisit the other language from time to time to see if you still feel the same way.

Comment: Oh, one more thing: for the love of God, don't pick a language because "all the [Ruby|PHP] guys seem really cool". Picture yourself interviewing for a job, getting asked "Why did you choose [Ruby|PHP] for your last project?", and then seeing the look on the interviewer's face when you say, "I just don't like [Ruby|PHP] people".  You don't want to become a joke on someone's blog.

Answer (score 1):

A few examples:

- PHP is more common on cheap hosting providers, and overall it requires less work to host a PHP app than one written in Ruby. So if want to write a platform to be widely distributed, such as wordpress, PHP is a better choice.
- Ruby is better suited for scripting than PHP. if you're not worried about something on the web, just a backend tool, then ruby is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that reasons to use one or the other are totally circumstantial, but you don't want any circumstantial ones :-).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give an answer. As you learn more and more programming languages, many people come to the conclusion "The right tool for the right job". Especially if you learn niche languages like Perl. It's a great tool for text processing and administrative work. It's not for commercial enterprise applications. That's what Java is for. Python is nice for scripting, Ruby is great for web applications.

On a meta level, Ruby is much safer. History shows that security and PHP do not go hand in hand very well. As a security consultant, my choice would be Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever language you are most comfortable with to get the job done well.  You're code is only as good as you are.